# Precompile pattern for simple strings, or regex only?

Tags: java, string

Use case:

```
for( String phrase : largeDictionary )
     phrase.split(",");
```

I understand why I should compile and reuse a pattern when splitting or matching a String against regex. I'm wondering if the same benefit holds for simple string literal or if there is a optimized code path that avoids regex altogether when it is unnecessary for splitting as in my case above with a comma. If I'm doing this often, should I still create and reuse a Pattern?

Comment: Until you can definitively prove that one code path is actively slowing down execution, **do not assume** and **do not prematurely optimize**.

Comment: There is a fast path for simple strings, but I don't know if it's faster than a precompiled regex. My guess is it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aString.split(",") - is FINE, you don't need Patterns for cases like this.
http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html
when pattern contains only one symbol (also known as delimeter) java use more simple way than using full-regex approach

```
   public String[] split(String regex, int limit) {
       /* fastpath if the regex is a
          (1)one-char String and this character is not one of the
             RegEx's meta characters ".$|()[{^?*+\\", or
          (2)two-char String and the first char is the backslash and
             the second is not the ascii digit or ascii letter.
       */
```

Comment: I clarified my question to indicate that this is done in a loop. Can you provide documentation or additional information as to why a Pattern isn't being compiled each time internally.

Comment: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html   line:2312


 fastpath if the regex is a (1)one-char String and this character is not one of the RegEx's meta characters ".$|()[{^?*+\\", or (2)two-char String and the first char is the backslash and the second is not the ascii digit or ascii letter.